# Is it safe to have just C++17 compatibility in a project?

Tags: c++17

I am starting a `C++` project from scratch. Is it safe to solely support `C++17`? In other words, is it recommended for any functionality implemented in a `C++17` way to have a corresponding functionality compatible with `C++11` or `C++14`?

Answer (score 2):

This has the notion of being opinion based but I think there is an objective view on this.

As a general rule I'd say, by the Ockham's Razor, it's bad to have different versions of the same functionality for whatever reason. Don't introduce it unless you have to. It's worse than copies.

Set for standard and be future ready - be ready to take on the new features once the target build infrastructure supports them, so that you can eventually deprecate and remove obsolete versions. There is a pretty good notion what's available in 3-6 years, so you can design your interfaces around it.

Providing backward standard compatibility is sometimes possible, but not always, and can be cumbersome. Assuming you start on some version and downgrade is a very risky idea.

You can't really say you use c++17 and provide backward compatibility, because it's impossible to do completely and keeping same interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

What sort of software?

For example in a library or an application in a Linux distribution you have to deal with your consumers, and likely some of them will still be on older OS's and compilers, and not want to update. For libraries if you want to provide some with new features in the API while supporting old ones you may need some functionality behind macro's/compile options (e.g. `std::string_view` where supported and `const std::string &` otherwise). For applications id say stick to the lowest version required.

However for an application you distribute can use whatever version you want and bundle the dependencies. So you could use a newer version of the compiler than the system comes with, rebuild boost C++, etc., just make sure you either static link or bundle any DLL/so you need.